# Use questionmark instead hashtag

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

i have a code that set me the value after the hashtag
i.e. http://www.mydoman.com/adv/#justexample  i need the value "justexample"
BUT i want to use questionmark instead hashtag:
http://www.mydomain.com/adv/?justexample

What i need to replace in this code:

```
<script>
        jQuery(function($){
            setTimeout(function(){
                var hash = window.location.hash+"";
                var cookieguardada = $.cookie("dv130312_r");
                var cookieactual = hash.substring(1);
                if((cookieguardada==null && cookieactual!="")||(cookieguardada!=null && cookieactual!="" && cookieguardada!=cookieactual)){
                    $.cookie("dv130312_r", "-" , { expires: -5, path: "/", domain: "'.$dominioprincipal.'"});
                    $.cookie("dv130312_r", hash.substring(1) , { expires: 7, path: "/", domain: "'.$dominioprincipal.'"});
                }
            },500);
        });
    </script>';
```

Comment: Hashtag is for the window hash, or the location on the same page.  Question mark specifies the beginning of the URL params, which are set by PHP and separated by ampersands (&), and are in a `key=value` format.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `window.location.hash` with `window.location.search`:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
        setTimeout(function(){
            var queryString = window.location.search+"";
            var cookieguardada = $.cookie("dv130312_r");
            var cookieactual = queryString.substring(1);
            if((cookieguardada==null && cookieactual!="")||(cookieguardada!=null && cookieactual!="" && cookieguardada!=cookieactual)){
                $.cookie("dv130312_r", "-" , { expires: -5, path: "/", domain: "'.$dominioprincipal.'"});
                $.cookie("dv130312_r", hash.substring(1) , { expires: 7, path: "/", domain: "'.$dominioprincipal.'"});
            }
        },500);
    });
</script>';
```